# Make ST_Polygonize in Postgis return dangles, cuts and invalid rings

Tags: postgis, postgresql, shapely, polygonize, python-3

Postgis allows using `ST_Polygonize()` from GEOS to make polygons out of lines. I have seen the same function available in Shapely library for Python, but in Shapely, the other method named `polygonize_full()` is also available.

In PostgreSQL 10.1 + PostGIS 2.3.0, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(foofoo.polycoll)).geom AS geomtextrep
FROM (SELECT ST_Polygonize(wkb_geometry) AS polycoll
FROM (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM the_table WHERE ST_GeometryType(wkb_geometry) = 'ST_LineString') AS foo) AS foofoo;
```

In Python3 + Shapely, I would do something like this:

```
result, dangles, cuts, invalids = polygonize_full(lines)
```

I have seen in the GEOS library that there are two functions:

```
GEOSPolygonize_full - Returns polygons, dangles, cuts, invalid rings
GEOSPolygonize - Returns only polygons
```

Is there any way to replicate the behaviour of GEOSPolygonize_full with PostGIS? I would like to use the dangles, cuts and invalids to judge whether I have missed out on some lines in the input data, and flag these events so I can manually check the source files (AutoCAD drawings) and associated layers.

I would hope ST_Polygonize_Full() maybe existed in PostGIS, but as far as I can see, it does not.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite an answer, but `ST_Polygonize` is defined in https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/postgis.sql.in

```
-- Availability: 1.4.0
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Polygonize (geometry[])
    RETURNS geometry
    AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME', 'polygonize_garray'
    LANGUAGE 'c' IMMUTABLE STRICT _PARALLEL
COST 1; -- reset cost, see #3675
```

i.e. it calls the function `polygonize_array`, defined in https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/lwgeom_geos.c, which calls `GEOSPolygonize`:

```
geos_result = GEOSPolygonize(vgeoms, nelems);
```

I couldn't find any reference to `GEOSPolygonize_full` in the PostGIS source though, so... not yet implemented?